# Is it possible to require attribute presence for angular's directive?

Tags: angularjs

I create a directive which requires particular attribute to present.

I can check attribute's value inside link function and throw exception.
Though it'd be nicer if some declarative way exists and `$compile` throws exception like it does when particular controller is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for and validate your attribute it in the `compile` function of the directive definition. This is how the Angular's native directives are built, for example [in the ng-repeat source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L245).

```
compile: function ngRepeatCompile($element, $attr) {
  var expression = $attr.ngRepeat;
  var match = expression.match(...);
  if (!match) {
    throw ngRepeatMinErr(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always check in your directive whether an attribute is present:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (!scope.title) {
                return false;//title attribute shouldn't be empty
            }
        },
```